# Using GOTO in ksh to return to already processed code

Tags: ksh, goto

I want the flow of control to go to code that has already been processed . Is their any way to do it
Some Code
...
...
Label
Some Code
...
...
GOTO Label

Basically I want a loop to be executed again after it has been already processed once.Based on certain condition

Comment: I'm sorry can you please edit your answer to make it more understandable. you've for , while loops in almost all languages which check for some condition and achieve same purpose you're using goto and label for. And please mention the language.

Comment: Hi Abhinav...I have to do this is in ksh script

Comment: ok I didn't realized something like ksh exists :D

Comment: @PrateekGupta why do not you write that part in the function.
Write the part of the code in a function and call whenever the condition gets fullfilled .

Answer (score 1):

You don't have goto, you need to implement it with other flow controls.
A small example where you can start after the comment main, start your normal processing with the function normal and restart normal when some_condition equals 2.

You can save the following script to a file (`gupta.sh`), chmod it (`chmod +x gupta.sh`) and call it 10 times (`./gupta.sh`) to see different random executions and modify.

```
#!/bin/ksh

function get_random {
   (( between_0_3 = ${RANDOM} % 4 ))
   echo "Random return= ${between_0_3}"
   return ${between_0_3}
}

function normal {
        echo "Start normal execution"
        get_random
        # Store the return value in a var
        some_condition=$?
        # ksh has a switch with the case keyword
        case ${some_condition} in
        0)
            echo "All went well"
            return 0
            # Syntax in case: finish with 2 ; characters
            ;;
        1)
            echo "OOPS, return error to main"
            return 1
            ;;
        2)   echo "This is the situation you want to restart (kind-of-goto)."
            return 2
            ;;
        *)   echo "Unexpected situation, stop without returning to main."
            exit 1
            ;;
        esac
}

# main
while [ 1 ]; do
   normal
   if [ $? -ne 2 ]; then
      break;
   fi
done
echo "End of main"
```

This is not the optimal example of flow control, but an example how to try to implement a goto. You should practice with for- and while loops.